# Readable Alias in Intellij

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I have a property file for my program. I want to store the file outside of my intellij project but want to see and change it like a file which is in the project. I tryied it with an alias but this dont work. Does anyone know a solution?

I use osx.

Kindly Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a symbolic link. 
In a terminal change your directory to the directory of your project. Then create a symbolic link. The first argument is the location of the existing file. The second argument is what you want to call the link in your project.

```
cd testProject    
ln -s ~/directoryWithFileIn/propertyFile.txt propertyFile.txt
```

When completed the link to your file will appear in the Project window with a little arrow in the top right hand corner of the icon

[image]